# Getting 2 lots of relationship data from a Laravel collection with Yajra Datatables

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-7, yajra-datatable

I am trying to get my Yajra Datatable working correctly but struggling.

Basically I want to get all clients appointments in which the client belongs to the logged in user. I then want to access the Client name and then the appointment data. I have used the following to get the appointment data

```
$user = User::find(Auth::user()->id);

$data = $user->clients()->with('appointments')->get()->pluck('appointments')->flatten();

return Datatables::of($data)
    ->make(true);
```

This allows me to show a row for each appointment that exists for the user-owned clients appointments. But how can I also access the clients name from this?

I have tried many different ways but if I use something like

`$data = $user->clients()->with('appointments')->get();`

I can access all of the data I need but it shows the existing clients in each row, not all appointments owned by the clients.

My setup is

User Model

```
    public function clients(){

        return $this->hasMany(Client::class);

    }

    public function appointments()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(Appointment::class, Client::class);
    }
```

Client Model

```
   public function appointments(){

        return $this->hasMany(Appointment::class);

    }

    public function users(){

        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);

    }
```

Appointment Model

```
 public function client(){

        return $this->belongsTo(Client::class);

    }
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be looking for `whereHas`:

```php
$appointments = Appointment::with('client')
    ->whereHas('client.users', function ($query) use ($user) {
        $query->where('users.id', $user->id)
    })
    ->get();
```

This translates to: "Give me all the appointments that belong to clients of a specific user".

Just a suggestion, it might be wise (not required at all) to alter your database structure to something more flexible. What if you for instance keep track in you appointment which user is present?

```
appointments
- user_id
- client_id
```

This would make your query a bit simpler

```php
// In User
public function appointments()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Appointment::class);
}

$user->appointments()->with('client')->get();
```

You could go even further by making the relation between `User` and `Appointment`, `Client` and `Appointment` many to many so you could have appointments with more than one user and/or client.